# How to open keyboard in flutter without TextField

Tags: flutter, dart

Open the keyboard without a text field or focusing Widget

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Show Keyboard

```
SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod("TextInput.show");
```

hide keyboard

```
SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod("TextInput.hide");
```

Comment: how do we specify the keyboard type with this method?